# Field Calculator Arc Map 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm learning as I go , I can't figure out the correct script.
I have data in a column named Full_Name which has 3 words  ex:  Arnault Branch Rd  and I want to break it out to StreetName column to be just the first two words Arnault Branch. The Script I'm using is !Full_Name!.split(" ", 1)[0][[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7th0.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good question should include detail of what you've already tried.  Please [edit] your question to include details of your attempts, and of what happens when you try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Python codeblock in field calculator:

Codeblock:

```
def two_words(field):
    result = field.split(' ')
    return result[0] + ' ' + result[1]
```

Field2:

```
two_words( !String!)
```

[image]

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Or without codeblock: `u' '.join(!Field!.split()[:-1])`